# Can the default browser be upgraded without upgrading the whole OS?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, browser

Can android 2.2 default browser be upgraded (without upgrading the whole OS) ?

Unfortunately, it is not available through Android market as far as I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot update inbuilt browser even though your phone is rooted. Anyway you have some other good alternative browsers in market like [Dolphin](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser), [Opera](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.opera.browser).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if the browser can be updated, even with root. The best thing is to root your device and install a better ROM, if you are stuck on an old Android version and unhappy with the browser.